# simple jquery animation - problems with too many mouse movements

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a simple drop menu I'm building in jquery. The code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/7Gpww/

it all seems fine, but if you move the mouse around a bit manically and don't wait for the full menu to load before you move to the next one, it'll hang. so for example, if I run the mouse across all the menu items quickly, letting the animation start but not get to the end, and then go back to SUPPORT for example, the dropdown menu will only load about half the items, like it's forgotten how long the `<ul>` should actually be.

I keep running into this in a few places. is there a way around this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `$('.menu .sub').hide();` instead of `$('.menu .sub').css('display', 'none');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Gpww/1/

You were almost there, you just needed to add calls to the `.stop()` function before each new animation to clear the previously queued animations.

Comment: Nice. Then you don't need the 'queue:false' anymore b/c you specify to clear queue in the 'stop()'